# Mapstruct ignore field, warning unmapped target properties

Tags: java, mapping, warnings, mapstruct, ignore

I am using mapstruct in Java and I need to get rid of warning: Warning: Unmapped target properties: "t3". I have the following structure:

```java
class A {
    String t1;
    String t2;
}

class B {
    String t1;
    String t2;
    String t3;
}
```

I am mapping with mapstruct from B to A class.

```
B toB(A a);
```

I would like to ignore just one field (t3), but `@Mapping` required target property, so I cannot use `@Mapping(source = "t3", ignore = true)`. Is there any solution for that?

TRYING: I was trying to use `@Mapping` and use `unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE`, but I want to ignore only specific field.

EXPECT: I would like to ignore just one field (t3), but `@Mapping` required target property, so I cannot use `@Mapping(source = "t3", ignore = true)`. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: `I am mapping with mapstruct from B to A class` - No, you are mapping A to B

Comment: ignore t3 is way to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@Mapping(target = "t3", ignore = true)` even if it belongs to the "source" not the "target" of the mapping.

Comment: I tried it and get "Unknown property "t3" in result type"

Comment: Are you by any chance using Lombok?

Comment: @JohnN please provide the code of mapping (put it to your question), because this solution works 100 percent

Comment: This is the right answer when mapping from A to B as asked in the question

Answer (score 0):

I made unmapped policies (for source and target) to throw errors and ignore the field `t3` for both mappings.

It worked fine with my testing.

```
import org.mapstruct.BeanMapping;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.ReportingPolicy;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;


@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface ABMapper {

    ABMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(ABMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "t1", target = "t1")
    @Mapping(source = "t2", target = "t2")
    @Mapping(target = "t3", ignore = true)
    B toB(A a);

    @Mapping(source = "t1", target = "t1")
    @Mapping(source = "t2", target = "t2")
    @BeanMapping(ignoreUnmappedSourceProperties = { "t3" })
    A toA(B b);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1718